# protect data file access in static app

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, web-applications, authorization

In a static web app (nothing except html, css and javascript),
I'm searching for a method to protect a file (*e.g.* json) from being accessed.

That file should only be accessible by authenticated and approved users. (I don't know yet how authentication will be handled.)

I can hide the view of the content in the application with userapp.io *e.g*., but I can't prevent someone to read it if he wanted to.

Would this be possible?

I thought of putting the protected file on www.firebase.com, but I could not find any practical example.

I also found solutions with .htaccess, but I need to avoid server dependent solutions.

*P.S.*: Not asking for code here ;-), just advice to point me in the right direction will do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit access through the web server (.htaccess), server-side code, or a third party solution.  If you want to keep your app static and want to avoid modifying .htaccess, then your best bet is to find a third party file host that offers authentication.  Would something like Box work for you?

If you're interested in putting your website on something like Weebly, then you can password protect certain pages.